# Use 'with' with dict to assign values

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a robust `dict` with many sub `dict`'s/`list`'s/`tuple`'s shouldn't I be able to use `with` statement to assign values to new names?

I mean:

```
# a dictionary with a complicated structure
d = {
    'names': ['Mark', 'Matteo', 'John'],
    'options': (1, 2),
    'sumting': { 'wong': [], 'etc': 'etc', 'habababa': 1 }
    }
# try to access some deeply hidden structure and
# pick to assign something to new names
with d['sumting'] as temp:
    new_name1 = temp['wong']
    new_name2 = temp['etc']
```

This yields:

```
>Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "<pyshell>", line 1, in <module>
>AttributeError: __enter__
```

Any other (better) way to avoid indexing the data structure (`dict`) multiple times apart from assigning a `temp` variable?

```
# consider same `dict` 'd'
temp = d['sumting']
new_name1 = temp['wong']
new_name2 = temp['etc']
del temp
```

Using `Python 3.6.1`

Comment: How would `with d['sumting'] as temp` (if it worked) be better than `temp = d['sumting']`? Variable used in the `with` statement won't be deleted in the end automatically, so you'll have to delete it yourself.

Comment: because it closes its context of coarse ;P

Comment: `with` is a keyword to handle context management, what exactly do you expect that to do in this scenario?

Comment: `d['sumting']` is a dictionary, not a context manager.

Comment: Please fix your grammar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assign to a temp variable, if you want to shorten its name:

```
temp = d['something']
a = temp['wrong']
b = temp['better']
```

[The `with` keyword means something totally different](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/) and very specific in Python, it doesn't just mean "Refer to X as Y"... that's what you have `Y = X` for.

Comment: important to note, `with something() as x:` *is an assignment*. It assigns whatever the context-manager `something()` returns to `x`.

Comment: 7 upvotes on this answer and you pretty much copied the code he has posted in his question

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: It assigns whatever the context manager's *`__enter__` method* returns to `x`.

Comment: @AK47 finders keepers ;P

Comment: @scnerd I only managed to hit 7 like 2 weeks ago and you get it with this answer haha

Comment: @user2357112 yes, that is correct. Sorry for the sloppy wording.